# Sending and receiving mail - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, email

Is there a framework that does such a thing. It's really important that it can check mail and get it's contents. For example:

If(newMessage hasSubjectEqualTo:@"woodviolins") {
}

And

If(contents of new message has "hey" in it) {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of frameworks in this general area. Google "Cocoa mail framework" and you'll come up with a bunch of hits. For one example: [Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/pantomime)

Comment: Is there an API or something for web based services? For example, verizon.net/aol.com

Comment: @Elijah W.: Many email hosts offer both Web interfaces and POP3 or IMAP. Verizon and AOL both do, as does Gmail.

Comment: Ok, and also, Pantomime seems very old and won't compile. Is there any newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

There's also c-client!

"Sending mail on Snow Leopard using the c-client API",

http://blog.loudhush.ro/2009/10/sending-mail-on-snow-leopard-using-c.html

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.